# Spring JDBC and Java 8 - JDBCTemplate: retrieving SQL statement and parameters for debugging

Tags: sql, lambda, java-8, spring-jdbc, spring-4

I am using Spring JDBC and some nice Java 8 lambda-syntax to execute queries with the JDBCTemplate.

The reason for choosing Springs JDBCTemplate, is the implicit resource-handling that Spring-jdbc offers (I do NOT want a ORM framework for my simple usecase's).

My problem is that I want to debug the whole SQL statements **with** their parameters. Spring prints the SQL by default but not the parameters. Therefor I have subclassed the JDBCTemplate and overridden a query-method.

An example usage of the JDBCTemplate:

```
    public List<Product> getProductsByModel(String modelName) {
    List<Product> productList = jdbcTemplate.query(
        "select * from product p, productmodel m " +
                "where p.modelId = m.id " +
                "and m.name = ?",
            (rs, rowNum) -> new Product(
                    rs.getInt("id"),
                    rs.getString("stc_number"),
                    rs.getString("version"),
                    getModelById(rs.getInt("modelId")), // method not shown
                    rs.getString("displayName"),
                    rs.getString("imageUrl")
            ),
                modelName);
    return productList;
}
```

To get hold of the parameters I have, as mentioned, overridden the JDBCTemplate class. By doing a cast and using reflection I get the Object[] field with the parameters from an instance of ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.

I suspect this implementation could potentially be dangerous, as the actual implementation of the PreparedStatementSetter may not always be ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter (Yes I should do an instanceOf check). Also, the reflection code may not be as elegant, but that is besides the point now though :).

Here's my custom implementation:

```
public class CustomJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJdbcTemplate.class);

public CustomJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
}

public <T> T query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, final PreparedStatementSetter pss, final ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
        throws DataAccessException {
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter aps = (ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter) pss;
        try {
            Field args = aps.getClass().getDeclaredField("args");
            args.setAccessible(true);
            Object[] parameters = (Object[]) args.get(aps);
            log.debug("Parameters for SQL query: " + Arrays.toString(parameters));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new GenericException(e.toString(), e);
        }
    }
    return super.query(psc, pss, rse);
}
}
```

So, when I execute the log.debug(...) statement I would also like to have the original SQL query logged (same line). Has anyone done something similar or are there any better suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

I do quite a few queries using this CustomJDBCTemplate and all my tests run, so I think it may be an acceptable solution of for most debug purposes.

Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the SQL-statement, so I will answer my own question :)

The `PreparedStatementCreator` has the following implementation:

```
private static class SimplePreparedStatementCreator implements PreparedStatementCreator, SqlProvider
```

So the `SqlProvider` has a `getSql()` method which does exactly what I need.

Posting the "improved" CustomJdbcTemplate class if anyone ever should need to do the same :)

```
public class CustomJdbcTemplate extends JdbcTemplate {
private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomJdbcTemplate.class);

public CustomJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    super(dataSource);
}

public <T> T query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, final PreparedStatementSetter pss, final ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
        throws DataAccessException {
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        if(pss instanceof ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter) {
            ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter aps = (ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter) pss;
            try {
                Field args = aps.getClass().getDeclaredField("args");
                args.setAccessible(true);
                Object[] parameters = (Object[]) args.get(aps);
                log.debug("SQL query: [{}]\tParams: {} ", getSql(psc), Arrays.toString(parameters));
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new GenericException(e.toString(), e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.query(psc, pss, rse);
}

private static String getSql(Object sqlProvider) { // this code is also found in the JDBCTemplate class 
    if (sqlProvider instanceof SqlProvider) {
        return ((SqlProvider) sqlProvider).getSql();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}